# Find the equations of two lines through the origin that are tangent to the ellipse equation: $2 {x^2} - 4 x + {y^2} + 1 = 0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, conic-sections, tangent-line

The answer is given. It is equal to $y = x \sqrt{2}$ and $y = -x \sqrt{2}$. Can you help me solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equation of both of the tangent lines to the ellipse $x^2 - 12x + y^2 + 7 = 0$ that pass through the origin.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2939530/equation-of-both-of-the-tangent-lines-to-the-ellipse-x2-12x-y2-7-0-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

The equation any straight line passing through the origin is $$y=mx$$

Replace $y$ as $mx$ in the given equation of ellipse to form a quadratic equation in $x$

For tangency, the roots must be same